# Get a `ReadableStream` from Node's `IncomingMessage` type (request)

Tags: node.js, node-fetch

I am using plain Node (v14 rn) and `node-fetch`. I need to pass on the incoming body on to a downstream fetch.

The `body` option on `node-fetch`'s `RequestInit` accepts:

| "Request body. can be null, a string, a Buffer, a Blob, or a Node.js Readable stream"

To minimize memory consumption I would prefer to hand over the readable stream to `fetch` vs read the contents of the body into a string first.

How can I generate a `ReadableStream` from `IncomingMessage` so I could write code something like this (pseudo-code)

```
async function(req:IncomingMessage, res:ServerResponse) {
   // need the magic inside toReadableStream
   const readableStream = toReadableStream(req);
   const result = await fetch('http://example.com', {
      method: "POST",
      body: readableStream,
   });
   // handle the result and send response to client
}
```